# GNU grub version 2.04 page

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

At first, I had windows 10 then I tried to install Ubuntu as a dual boot but then I couldn't do it so, I deleted the windows data and installed Ubuntu intentionally. then everything went well but when I'm rebooting my device I'm stuck on that grub page. I've found a temporary working command which I put every time I boot. so I can boot my device... Can somebody give me a permanent solution, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score -1):

I got this solution from Ubuntu itself and it worked smoothly, so do it step by step carefully.

- Connect to the Internet
- Open a new Terminal, then type the following commands (press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after each line):

  ```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
  ```